# Convergence in probability of quantiles

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $\hat F_n$ be a sequence of estimators of a cumulative distribution $F$. If

$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|\hat F_{n}(x)-F(x)| \longrightarrow_{\mathbb{P}} 0,$$

does it hold that for a fixed $\alpha \in (0,1)$,

$$\hat F^{-1}_n(\alpha)\longrightarrow_{\mathbb{P}} F^{-1}(\alpha) ?$$

You can assume all distributions are continuous.

Comment: When you say $F^{-1}(\alpha)$ do you mean $\sup\{ x\in \mathbb{R}\vert F(x)<\alpha \}$?

Comment: Yes I do; the generalized inverse.

Comment: And you assume $\hat{F}_n$ are distribution functions, right?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur yes